# bootstrap elements overlapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have a really simple bit of bootstrap that is in a vue.js file.
the
   `<div v-for="location in 5">`
simply prints 5 font awesome icons next to "location:"
This works fine for most of my responsive cases,however whilst I am dragging my screen around the font awesome icons overlap the location text(when Its between md and sm I predict). This still happens if I wrap it in a container.

Has anyone insight to why?

Thanks

```
 <div id="location-section" class="section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div >Locations:</div>
        </div>
        <div v-for="location in 5">
          <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using only `col-md-3`. It makes it responsive only for screen sizes greater than 991px, Hence you are having the issue. Use `col-xs-3` that will make it responsive for all screen sizes.

try this--

```
 <div id="location-section" class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div >Locations:</div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="location in 5">
      <div class="col-xs-3 ">
        <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```